# Bootstrap nav bar not centering correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I have a navigation bar created using bootstrap, but for some reason it is not totally centered. It is off center to the left and I can't figure out why it is not perfectly centered. Below is the code for it.

```
  <body>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) --> 
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as 
needed --> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <div class="row">
 <nav class="navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="mainNav">
        <li><a href="###">Locations</a></li>
        <li><a href="###">Special Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="###">Breakfast</a></li>
        <li><a href="###">Lunch</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html" class="active text-uppercase">Liam's Food 
       Fusion</a></li>
        <li><a href="###">Dinner</a></li>
        <li><a href="###">Apps and Extras</a></li>
        <li><a href="###">Online Ordering</a></li>
        <li><a href="###">Contact Us</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
    </div>
</nav>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this CSS.

```
.navbar-default > .container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```css
.navbar-default>.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header center-block">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="mainNav">
            <li><a href="###">Locations</a></li>
            <li><a href="###">Special Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="###">Breakfast</a></li>
            <li><a href="###">Lunch</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html" class="active text-uppercase">Liam's Food
                            Fusion</a></li>
            <li><a href="###">Dinner</a></li>
            <li><a href="###">Apps and Extras</a></li>
            <li><a href="###">Online Ordering</a></li>
            <li><a href="###">Contact Us</a></li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```